Passing variables between userforms
I have a Digital Decision Matrix userform (frmMatrix) where the user enters "Heat Index" and "Population of Interest" and is returned a statement of recommended protective measures.
They are asked if they would like to make a record of these protective measures in my Automated Log userform (frmForm).
Upon clicking yes, I would like my Automated Log userform to display the "Heat Index" and "Population of Interest" fields with the values entered in frmMatrix.
The Automated Log form values loaded into the "Heat Index" and "Population of Interest" fields are those entered two entries ago.
For example, the user makes consecutive entries into frmMatrix:
#1: "83" and "Athletes"  
#2: "85" and "Children"  
#3: "87" and "Outdoor Workers"  

After making entry #2 and selecting "Yes", the Automated Log form will open with the values "83" and "Athletes" in the "Heat Index" and "Population of Interest" fields (the responses given in example #1).
After making entry #3 and selecting "Yes", the Automated Log form will open with the values "85" and "Children" (the responses given in example #2).
Option Explicit
Public index As Integer
Public category As String
Public population As String

Private Sub cmdGo_Click()

    If ValidateMatrixEntries() = True Then
    
        index = frmMatrix.txtIndex.Object.Value
        population = frmMatrix.cmbPopulation.Object.Value
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
        'Heat Stress Category 1
        If index < 80 Then
        
            category = "Category 1"

            '(nonrelevant code follows for outputting protective measures)
            '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Dim AnswerYes As String
        Dim AnswerNo As String
        
        AnswerYes = MsgBox("Would you like to record these actions in the log?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Record Entry")
        
        If AnswerYes = vbYes Then
            Call Preset_Form
            Unload frmMatrix
        Else
            Unload frmMatrix
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Preset_Form()
    frmForm.Show
    frmForm.txtIndex.Value = index
    frmForm.cmbPopulation.Value = population
    frmForm.cmbAction.Value = category
End Sub

Digital Decision Matrix:

Automated Log:


Maybe not the root of your problem here, but in the userform code module, it's best to refer to the current form instance as Me.  Also - take a look here from some useful advice on showing userforms: https://rubberduckvba.blog/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

You need to change your Preset_Form logic to show the form AFTER the assignments:
Public Sub Preset_Form()
   frmForm.txtIndex.Value = index
   frmForm.cmbPopulation.Value = population
   frmForm.cmbAction.Value = category
   frmForm.Show
End Sub

The reason is Show doesn't return until after the form is closed so the values don't get assigned soon enough.  In affect you are always one entry behind.
